# In order to get a speed boost for my python program, should I spawn a separate thread or a separate process for logging?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance

In order to get a speed boost for my python program, should I spawn a separate thread or a separate process for logging? My program uses a lot of logging and I am not sure if threading is suitable because of GIL. A lot of resources seem to suggest that it should be fine for I/O. I think that logging is I/O but I am not sure what does "should be fine" mean for most of the resources out there. I just need speed.

Comment: What makes you believe that logging is the bottleneck? If you have not done so already, you will want to profile your program to see where the majority of the latency is occurring.

Comment: @MrName I just want to eliminate every single millisecond that I can possibly eliminate. My code has to run 10million times and every millisecond counts. Or are you suggesting 10m * 200 = 2b lines of log shouldn't matter that much?

Comment: I would assume that the performance cost of your logging calls would be heavily dependent on the logging handlers. Threading MIGHT help, but it might be even better to run these type of things in background tasks, so that the execution time of the logging call is no longer bound to your application execution time.

Comment: @MrName how to run logging as background task？

Comment: There are a lot of options, but you could start with a messaging queue perhaps. In this setup, you would still incur the cost of queueing the task. Depending on your task runner, this could still be faster than logging directly. http://python-rq.org/ is a relatively simple and fast queue that you might want to try for prototyping.

Comment: this question has an open bounty and so I can't vote to close.  But the question isn't clear.  You don't say what type of logging you are doing.  You don't say what you have tried.  So might threading help your IO problem?  Impossible to say

Comment: @Vorsprung using python logging module

Answer (score 9):

Before you start trying to optimize a program, there are some things you should do.

To start with, you should *profile* you programs. You could e.g. use [line_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/).

If it turns out that your software spends a considerable amount of time logging, there are two easy options.

- Set the loglevel in production code so that no or few(er) messages are logged. There will still be some overhead left, but it should be much reduced.
- Use mechanical means (like `sed` or `grep`) to *completely remove* the logging calls from the production code. If this doesn't improve the speed/throughput of your program, logging wasn't an issue.

If neither of those is suitable and logging is a significant fraction of your programs time you can try to implement thread or process based logging.

If you want to use `threading` for logging, you will besically need a list and a lock. The function that is called from the main thread to do logging grabs the lock, appends the text to log to the list and releases the lock. The second thread waits for the lock, grabs the lock, pops a couple of items from the list, releases the lock and writes the items to a file. Since the GIL makes sure that only one thread at a time is running Python bytecode, this will reduce the performance of your program somewhat; part of its time is spent running the bytecode from the logging thread.

Using `multiprocessing` is slightly different, in that you probably want to use e.g. a `Queue` to send logging messages from the main process to the logging process. The logging process takes items from the Queue and writes them to disk. This means that the time spent writing the logging actions to disk is spent in a different program. But there is some overhead associated with using a Queue as well.

You would have to *measure* to see which method uses less time in your program.

Answer (score 0):

I am going by these assumptions:

- You already determine that it is your logging that is bottlenecking your program.
- You have a good reason why you are logging what you are logging.

The perceived slowness is most likely due to the success or failure acknowledgement from the logging action. To avoid this "command queuing" make the calls to a separate process asynchonously and skipping the callback. This may end up consuming more resources, but this will alleviate the backlog in your main program. 
Nodejs handles this naturally or you can roll your own python listener. Since this will be a separate process. You can redirect the logging feature of your other programs to this one. You can even have a separate machine to handle this workload.